# Does pivoting a discrete CDF provide a pivot?

Tags: confidence-interval, pivot

In Section 9.2.3 of Casella's Statistical Inference,
they base their confidence interval construction for a parameter $\theta$ on a real-valued statistic $T$ with cdf $F_T(t| \theta)$.

1. They first assume that $T$ is a continuous random variable.
   Then by the Probability Integral Transformation, the continuous random variable $F (T | \theta)$ is uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$, and therefore is a pivot which can be used to construct a confidence region.
   [image]
2. They say the situation where $T$ is discrete is similar but has a few additional technical details to consider.

   [image]

   My question is when $T$ has a discrete distribution. In such case, $F (T | \theta)$ takes countably many values and is not uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$. Does the distribution of $F (T | \theta)$ depend on $\theta$, and therefore it is not a pivot? In such case, why can Casella still think it as a pivot, or am I missing something?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3):

It is not a pivot. However the resulting interval is guaranteed to have at least the  stated coverage. For the discrete distribution the coverage could be  a lot higher than stated.

Comment: I'm sure you did not mean to use the word "diapered" ([look it up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diaper)). What do you mean?