# Confidence Interval of shifted exponential

Tags: self-study, distributions, confidence-interval, inference

[image].
 I know what confidence intervals are but can a confidence interval of given size have different lengths?

Comment: Look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367881/confidence-interval-for-shift-parameter-of-a-shifted-exponential-distribution?rq=1) and at the 'duplicate' page referenced there.

Comment: Could you tell us what you understand a confidence interval to be?  Apparently it differs from what the question is trying to teach you, so it would help to know where the discrepancy lies.